# Does Flash support generics (strong typed collection or array)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can I strongly type an array in Actionscript ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an Array, but if you're targeting Flash Player 10 or higher you can use Vector

```
var v:Vector.<Sprite>;
```

v is now a strongly typed collection that should only accept Sprite objects.

It's the closest you'll get to generics.

Comment: It's worth noting that Vectors are treated as a hash-table, whereas arrays are *not*. Vectors will give you better performance for collections of specific types.